# Finding a continuous probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expectation

The support of a continuous random variables is $\text{{$u;f_X(u)>0$}}$.

This clue has been provided: "A theorem states that the sequence $(E[X^n])_n$ for all natural $n$ completely characterises the distribution of random variables with bounded support; in other words two different distributions with bounded support differ in some of the moments.

Suppose $E[X^i]=\frac{1}{i+1}$ for all natural $i$. Find the distribution of $X$.

How on earth does one approach this problem? The clue has only confused me.

So far all I have ascertained is that the sequence in question is $$(E[X^n])_n=\frac{1}2,\frac{1}3,\frac{1}4...\frac{1}n$$
How do I approach this?

Comment: Uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$ satisfies these conditions. I don't know how this clue could help. Maybe it just shows that there is no other example.

Comment: If you are given all the moments, this will define the characteristic function or the moment generating function.  Either one can then be inverted to get the probability distribution function or (if it exists) the density function.